# what does the JavascriptExecutor declaration actually means

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java

I am trying to understand the meaning of the following declaration:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
```

I know that the left side means to create an identifier js with type as  JavascriptExecutor, but I am unable to understand what the right-hand syntax means

I read like JavascriptExecutor is an interface and that interfaces cannot be initialized. So what does the code actually does here

Comment: This is a very basic Java question, it's not specific to QA. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9344271/parentheses-around-data-type

Comment: Thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drivers seems implementations of JavascriptExecutor.
So it can be type casting.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html . You could read more about this at the mentioned link

[image]

Comment: @PDHide Thank you for your editing.